# Replace the values of one list with the closest values of another list

Tags: python, list, replace, compare

I have two lists:

```
list_1= [123, 122, 524, 500, 515, 600, 620]
list_2= [120, 150, 500, 550, 600, 650]
```

I would like to replace the values in list_1 with the closest values in list_2 and my result would look like:

```
new_list= [120,120,500,500,500,600,600]
```

would be great to get some help!

I am new to python and I am trying to find similar solutions. My logic behind it would be:

```
for j in list_2:
for i in enumerate(list_1):
    if j==i: (here I would need a conditional to say if it is close to value j)
```

An idea would be to subtract value j in list_2 from value i in list_1 and if the result is less than 50 then it will replace i with J , else it will return i.

How I tried to write it (no success so far):

```
 if i-j<=50 :
    list_1[i]= list[i].replace(j,i)

 else:
    return i
```

Comment: post your current code

Comment: here you go! I hope it gives an idea of what I am trying to do. But still a beginner..

Answer (score 2):

```
list_1= [123, 122, 524, 500, 515, 600, 620]
list_2= [120, 150, 500, 550, 600, 650]
new_list = list_1[:]
for i, v in enumerate(list_1):
    ok = []
    for j, k in enumerate(list_2):
        ok.append(abs(v-k))
    # find the index of the closet element from list_2 to the current v
    ind = ok.index(min(ok))
    new_list[i] = list_2[ind]
print(new_list)

#[120, 120, 500, 500, 500, 600, 600]
```